# Relationship between two tables based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi

I have two tables/dataframes which I want to connect via a relationship with each other (1:1, n:m,...). The first table has one column with names of different people and the books they worked on. The second table is for a network graph and shows each relationship between the people (basically who worked with who and on which book).

Table 1:

| name | book ID |
| --- | --- |
| alex | 1 |
| dave | 2 |
| mona | 1,2 |

Table 2:

| name 1 | name 2 | book ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alex | mona | 1 |
| dave | mona | 2 |

For cross-filtering in Power BI i would like to generate a relationship between these two tables. Is there any opportunity to link the two tables with a unique ID or is there another way to do it? It also won't be a problem if i have to modify the tables via python (pandas) or create ana dditional one.

thanks in advance!

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create bridge tables and you those to link the tables.

Try to follow the examples shown [here](https://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/join-many-many-power-bi/) and use them on your problem